# Getting a SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed' with Entity Framework Core when updating a record

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have an invoice object that has a client object as a property. I am getting this SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Client.InvoiceId' when I try to update my Invoice object. I tried doing what another article on the same problem suggested, and that is adding an Attach statement before calling SaveChanges() but that didn't work:

```
_context.Invoices.Attach(invoice);
```

Here's my data model:

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateInvoiceID();
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDue { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; } = "pending";
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        

        public string BillFromAddress { get; set; }
        public string BillFromCity { get; set; }
        public string BillFromCountry { get; set; }
        public string BillFromPostal { get; set; }

    }

public class Client
    {
        public string ClientId{ get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateClientID();
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientCity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientCountry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ClientPostal { get; set; }
   
    }

public class InvoiceItem
    {
        public string InvoiceItemId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateItemID();
        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public InvoiceItem()
        {
        }

        public InvoiceItem(string itemName, int quantity, int price)
        {
            Name = itemName;
            Quantity = quantity;
            Price = price;
        }  
    }
```

Here is the service that updates the invoice:

```
public async void EditInvoice(InputModel input, string id)
        {
            var invoice = await _context.Invoices.FindAsync(id);

            if (invoice == null) { throw new Exception("Unable to find the invoice"); }

            invoice.Items = input.Items;

            invoice.Description = input.Description;
            invoice.InvoiceDate = input.InvoiceDate;
            invoice.PaymentTerms = input.PaymentTerms;
            invoice.Client = input.Client;

            
            invoice.BillFromAddress = input.BillFromAddress;
            invoice.BillFromCity = input.BillFromCity;
            invoice.BillFromCountry = input.BillFromCountry;
            invoice.BillFromPostal = input.BillFromPostal;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Here's my InputModel class:

```
public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

        public string PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        public DateTime PaymentDue { get; set; }


        public Client Client { get; set; }

        
        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>(16);


        [Required]
        public string BillFromAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromCity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromCountry { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BillFromPostal { get; set; }


        public void PopulateItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(new InvoiceItem());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my CreateInvoice PageModel

```
 public class CreateInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {
        
        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public CreateInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {
            Input = new InputModel();
            Input.PopulateItems();
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.AddInvoice(Input);
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            return Page();

        }

    }
```

Here's my EditInvoice PageModel

```
public class EditInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {

        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public EditInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        
        public async void OnGet(string id)
        {
            Invoice invoice = await _service.GetInvoice(id);
            InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId;
            Input = new InputModel();

            Input.Items = invoice.Items;

            Input.BillFromAddress = invoice.BillFromAddress;
            Input.BillFromCity = invoice.BillFromCity;
            Input.BillFromPostal = invoice.BillFromPostal;
            Input.BillFromCountry = invoice.BillFromCountry;

            Input.Client = invoice.Client;

            Input.InvoiceDate = invoice.InvoiceDate;
            Input.PaymentTerms = invoice.PaymentTerms;
            Input.Description = invoice.Description;

        }

        public  async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string id)
        {
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.EditInvoice(Input, id);
                return RedirectToPage("/ViewInvoice", new { id = id });
            }

            return Page();
        }

    }
```

Here's my DbContext class:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your `InputModel` details? You are getting the error because within  the same method you are trying to manipulate the `_context` twice. You should try this way 
`using (var context = new AppDbContext ())
{
… Your EditInvoice method body code here
}`. Use same context to execute `read-write` operation within the same `_context`. Let's try it and share your update hows going forward. You can [`have a look here in this link`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15819)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't quite understand what you are saying. How am I trying to manipulate `_context` twice within the same method ? I added the code for `InputModel` if you want to take a look.

Comment: Your Client to Invoice relation looks off. I assume one Client can have multiple Invoices?

Comment: @JayFridge Correct. One client can have multiple invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i assume is happening is that the ChangeTracker tracks the Client you set in your EditInvoice method as a new entity and tries to insert it into the database. But because you mapped Client and Invoice as a 1 to 1 relation the insert fails.

So since one client can really have multiple invoices you need to make the following changes:

**Client**
Remove the `InvoiceId`

```cs
public class Client
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateClientID();
    // public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    /* omitted for brevity */
}
```

Really delete this line. I just commented it out to make it clear.

**Invoice**
Add the `ClientId`

```cs
public class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; } = GenerateID.GenerateInvoiceID();
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    /* omitted for brevity */
}
```

**InputModel**
Change the `Client` object to `ClientId`

```cs
public class InputModel
{
    // public Client Client { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
   /* omitted for brevity */
}
```

**EditInvoice method**
Update the ClientId instead of the whole Client object

```cs
invoice.ClientId = input.ClientId;
```

You can read more about relationships in EntityFrameworkCore [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: But why would I remove the `Client` property from my `InputModel` class. How would I bind the user's input to the properties in `Client` object ?

Comment: The question is do you want to create a new Client when you are editing an invoice? Or do you want to be able to link an existing one? Can the Client change at all for an invoice you are editing?

Comment: I definitely don't want to create a new client object when editing. I am just wondering how can I bind user's input to a client object at creation if I delete it from `InputModel`. I added the code for my `CreateInvoice` and `EditInvoice` PageModels for more information.